# Lossless video writing using opencv CudaCodec in linux

Tags: c++, opencv, nvidia, codec

I'm using Opencv cuda. I want to write video frames from `original.avi` to another `.avi` file using `cudacodec::VideoWriter` without any loss. The logged video file suze is less than original video. what codec value should be passed ? lossless logging is applicable?

Help me. cudacodec VideoReader and VideoWriter working perfectly in my linux pc.

I am trying it in linux using c++.

Comment: It only supports AVC and HEVC which aren't lossless codecs https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d0/d61/group__cudacodec.html#gaa8819563e409f6aab72c20bab5fdf151